# When I click on checkbox the fields i checked should display in dropdown

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

When I click on checkbox, the fields I checked should be displayed in dropdown.

```python
class my_friends(osv.osv):
    _name = "my.friends"
    _description = "My Friends"
    _columns = {   
        'name': fields.char('Name'),
        'selection': fields.selection([
                ('grade','Grade'), 
                ('designation','Designation'),
                ('score','Score')
            ],
            string='Selection'),
}
```

The checkboxes are defined in another class. If I click in a checkbox of grade it should show in the selection field otherwise it should not show.